# Why is my logical comparison of the same number returning false?

Tags: javascript, node.js, serverless

In the following function, I am comparing item.id to ID, "type of" shows that they are both strings but the comparison is failing. 1234 === 1234 returns false, for instance.

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
  if (!event.pathParameters || !event.pathParameters.ID) {
    return Responses._400({ message: "missing ID" });
  }

  console.log("data  ", data);

  let ID = event.pathParameters.ID;

  data.find((item) => {
    console.log("item.id, ID", item.id, ID);

    if (item.id.trim() === ID.trim()) {
      return Responses._200(item);
    }
  });

 return Responses._400({ message: "id not found", ID });
}
```

This is the array of data:

```
const data = [
  {
    id: "1234",
    email: "user1@user1.com",
    username: "user1",
    createdAt: "2020-09-10T14:03:09.203Z",
   __v: 0,
  },
  {
    id: "5678",
    email: "user1@user1.com",
    username: "user1",
    createdAt: "2020-09-10T14:03:09.203Z",
    __v: 0,
  },
];
```

The call to the function originates from the browser as follows:

```
https://hs40xxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/get-user/1234
```

Comment: Assuming you're using mongodb, `data.find` is asynchronous and you always return the 400 response before the ids even get compared in the first place. Put that in an `else` clause instead.

Comment: Array.prototype.find() is synchronous. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: Oops, I missed that `data` is an array. In that case, Maxim is right: the `return` statement just doesn't work like that in a `find` callback.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `find` and `return` in the wrong way.

See what gets returned with your current approach:

```js
const data = [
  {
    id: "1234",
    email: "user1@user1.com",
    username: "user1",
    createdAt: "2020-09-10T14:03:09.203Z",
   __v: 0,
  },
  {
    id: "5678",
    email: "user1@user1.com",
    username: "user1",
    createdAt: "2020-09-10T14:03:09.203Z",
    __v: 0,
  },
];

const ID = "1234";

const test = () => {
  data.find((item) => {
    console.log("item.id, ID", item.id, ID);

    if (item.id.trim() === ID.trim()) {
      return 200;
    }
  });
}

console.log(test());
```

It's `undefined`.

Instead, you should do this:

```js
const data = [
  {
    id: "1234",
    email: "user1@user1.com",
    username: "user1",
    createdAt: "2020-09-10T14:03:09.203Z",
   __v: 0,
  },
  {
    id: "5678",
    email: "user1@user1.com",
    username: "user1",
    createdAt: "2020-09-10T14:03:09.203Z",
    __v: 0,
  },
];

const ID = "1234";

const test = () => {
  const found = data.find((item) => {
    console.log("item.id, ID", item.id, ID);

    return item.id.trim() === ID.trim();
  });
  if (found) {
    return 200;
  }
}

console.log(test());
```

Now you're returning status `200` from the outer function, not inside of the `find` function.

You can read more about how `find` works here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Essentially, inside of `find()` you should return false if it's not a match and true if it's a match.

Comment: If you're not actually interesting in the `item` itself, I'd recommend using `some` instead of `find`.

Comment: Yes, I agree, `some` is more appropriate here, but that's beyond the point. I was trying to show why it wasn't working and how to make it work :)

Comment: @koque have you tried this solution? Did it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

from what I see you are not using find to return a value that qualifies itself rather you impose your own return there, find method actually returns the first element in the array that passes the condition so use the condition with return and try it the other way.

```
      Responses._200(data.find(item => {
       console.log("item.id, ID", item.id, ID);
       return item.id.trim() === ID.trim() 
      }));
```

or store the value of data.find in a value and send a response in another way.

Comment: Your method produced the same result. Previously I had data.find(item => item.id === ID) and received the same result.